# self referencing generic with inheritence

Tags: vb.net, generics

I have a class AnimalQueue which is a queue of Animals.  Each queue will only store a certain type of Animal, and I want to make sure that only Animals that match the type of the queue are added to it:

```
Public Class AnimalQueue(Of T As Animal)
    Public Sub Add(pA As T)
    End Sub
End Class
```

When an Animal in the queue is processed, I want to pass the queue that is processing it to the Animal in case the Animal wants to add another Animal to the same queue:

```
Public MustInherit Class Animal
    Public MustOverride Sub Process(Of T As Animal)(pAQ As AnimalQueue(Of T))
End Class
```

The problem is that when I add a concrete class I get a compile error at the call to Add:

```
Public Class Horse
    Inherits Animal

    Public Overrides Sub Process(Of T As Animal)(pAQ As AnimalQueue(Of T))
        pAQ.Add(New Horse())
    End Sub
End Class
```

It says Horse can't be converted to T, but the constraint says that T is an Animal and Horse is an Animal...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `T` might be any class that is derived from animal. Assume the following class hierarchy:

```
Horse -> Animal
Dog -> Animal
```

In your code, the generic parameter `T` of `Process` is constrained to be **any** animal. So even if you implement it on the `Horse` class, the following call would be perfectly valid:

```
Dim dogQ As New AnimalQueue(Of Dog)()
Dim h As New Horse()
h.Process(Of Dog)(dogQ)
```

In this case, your implementation of `Process` would try to add a `Horse` to a queue of `Dogs`. As `Horse` is not derived from `Dog`, you cannot do this.

I assume that you want to create a method so that the `Process` method of `Horse` only accepts a queue of `Horses` and the `Process` method of `Dog` only accepts a queue of `Dogs`.

There are several ways to accomplish this:

1. Do not create a generic `Process` method on the level of the base class, but only `Process` methods on the level of the children (e.g. for `Horse`: `Public Sub Process(horseQ As AnimalQueue(Of Horse))`).
2. Use a `New` constraint and implement the method on the level of `Animal`. In your comments, you mention that your animals need constructor parameters, so this is not an option.
3. If you want to have a base class that defines the generic method, you could create the following structure:

---

```
Public Class AnimalQueue(Of T As Animal)
    Public Sub Add(animal As T)
        ' ...
    End Sub
End Class

Public MustInherit Class Animal

End Class

Public MustInherit Class ProcessableAnimal(Of T As Animal)
    Inherits Animal

    Public MustOverride Sub Process(q As AnimalQueue(Of T))

End Class

Public Class Horse
    Inherits ProcessableAnimal(Of Horse)

    Public Overrides Sub Process(q As AnimalQueue(Of Horse))
        q.Add(New Horse())
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Dog
    Inherits ProcessableAnimal(Of Dog)

    Public Overrides Sub Process(q As AnimalQueue(Of Dog))
        q.Add(New Dog())
    End Sub
End Class
```

In this approach, there is a new level of inheritance. But the significant change is that you set the generic type parameter on class level. So the decision is made when deriving from `ProcessableAninmal` and is not left to the caller of `Process`.

```
Dim h As New Horse()
Dim hQ As New AnimalQueue(Of Horse)()
Dim dQ As New AnimalQueue(Of Dog)()
h.Process(hQ) ' Valid
h.Process(dQ) ' NOT VALID ANYMORE
```

Comment: I still don't understand why I can't pass a Horse to Add, since it's expecting T As Animal

I can't move the creation of the Animal into AnimalQueue because a lot of Animals will need parameters passed to their constructors.

Comment: @ghosttie: I've clarified my answer a bit. I hope that it helps; if not, let me know.

Comment: The problem now is that AnimalQueue needs to be able to call Process, but it has Animals not ProcessableAnimals

Comment: @ghosttie: Maybe you can move the `Process` method to `AnimalQueue` and have it take a parameter of `T` instead of creating the animal in the `Process` method. Or you could change the `Process` method so that it does not create the animal and add it to the queue, but only processes the animal that it is called upon. Then you could define the method on the level of `Animal` and therefore use it in `AnimalQueue`. The root cause of the problem is that the method does do too much and also couples the `Animal` to tightly to a specific kind of collection, the `AnimalQueue` in your sample.